# Wordpress - Admin-AJAX is not saving meta data

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Trying to use the built in AJAX functions with the Wordpress Admin.  I've been following [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) tutorial, but when I run the jQuery script, the data isn't being saved to the user meta.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ring_jquery' );

    function ring_jquery() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.ring-submit').on('click', function(){
        var u = jQuery(this).attr('user'),
            c = jQuery('.agt_ringc[user="'+u+'"]').val(),
            x = jQuery('.agt_ringx[user="'+u+'"]').val(),
            formData = 'ringu='+u+'&ringc='+c+'&ringx='+x;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(e){

                jQuery('.success[user="'+u+'"]').fadeIn(400).delay(400).fadeOut(400);

            },
            error: function(){

                jQuery('.fail[user="'+u+'"]').fadeIn(400).delay(400).fadeOut(400);

            }
        });
    });

</script>
<?php
} //End ring_jquery()

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'ring_callback');

function ring_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $ringu = $_POST['ringu'];
    $ringc = $_POST['ringc'];
    $ringx = $_POST['ringx'];

    update_user_meta($ringu,'agt_ringc',$ringc);
    update_user_meta($ringu,'agt_ringx',$ringx);

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
?>
```

Comment: you do not have `action : my_action` .. and Iamnot sure about the `$_POST` being available .. try first with simple strings inside the function .

Comment: That’s because you need a function in PHP code listening to the action and actually saving the data. JavaScript alone cannot do that.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: Ok, went back through the codex and a couple examples, added `action=ring_callback` to the `formData` variable, but still nothing.  Could you be more specific?  Is there anything I need to flush inorder to get it to work?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: Ok, jostled some stuff around, gave it a good whack with a hammer and it seems to be functioning properly now. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have `action : my_action` in the data string , or as per codex :

```
var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: 1234
    };
```

Comment: took ya long enough! :P

Answer (score 0):

Issue was, as @ObmerkKronen pointed out was that I was missing an action definition in the data string (which tells the AJAX page which function to run).

```
formData = 'action=ring_callback&ringu='+u+'&ringc='+c+'&ringx='+x;
```

I also changed the name of the action hook to match the name of the function.  I don't know if this was necessary, but some other things I found did it and I wanted to fit in.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ring_callback', 'ring_callback');
```